# how to go to a specific folder in c++ with a specific address

Tags: c++, file, directory

I need to go to a specific address in a C++ file and create folders inside that.

This is the folder address

> C:\Users\218418\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Netwokring Application\Netwokring Application\CENTRAL

(I know I spelled Networking wrong, dont judge me)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't need to "go to" a folder to create files in it. Just append the filename to the folder name and create that.

Comment: Folders don't have addresses, and you can't put folders into files, so it is unclear as to what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This does creates a folder in the given directory. I believe you wanted to create directories inside the given path of yours.

Program checks if the directory exists, and if not creates it. (Given it has permissions to do so.)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

void create_folder(const char * path)
{   
    if(!CreateDirectory(path , nullptr))
    {}
}

int main()
{
    const std::string folder_name = "test_folder";
    const std::string base_path =
        "C:\\Users\\218418\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Netwokring Application\\Netwokring Application\\CENTRAL\\";
    std::string result = base_path + folder_name;
    create_folder(result.c_str());
}
```

Comment: or portable [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) in C++17.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to create/open a file during runtime and read/write to/from it.

[**Files and Streams**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_files_streams.htm)

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
ifstream file("your_file.txt");
```

Will open a stream `file` which can read from *your_file.txt* in your working directory. (where you keep your compiled .exe)

And now, this is how you can use specific file path:

```
char *path="C:\Windows\your_file.txt";
std::ofstream file(path);
```